# What would I need to change when copy pasting a React.js app?

Tags: reactjs

I've built for myself a template that I'd like to use for all my projects. It has all my favorite styles set up, certain components etc.

If I want to start a new project, can I just copy paste this whole folder and rename it?

I am new to React and don't know exactly what happens under the hood. Other than making sure external services are reconfigured properly (for example Firebase), is there anything else I'll need to change? Is there any unique stamping created when I use `create-react-app`? Or is a simple copy-paste completely safe to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes copy paste will work, But make sure you run npm install first.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this repository as a template repository for your other projects. To make this a template repository on `GitHub`, go to `settings` and under `options` tab check `template repository`.

[template repository snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJUEL.png)